# SQL: Getting data from several tables

Tags: sql

I have the following:

```
SELECT  
   f.Korsnamn AS Foto, ä.ID AS ÄrendeID, ä.Kortnamn AS Ärende, l.Kortnamn AS Labb
FROM    
   Foto f, Ärendet ä, Labbrapport l
WHERE   
   f.ÄrendeID = ä.ID
```

Which returns:

```
Foto  ÄrendeID  Ärende  Labb
1123       10   asd      sdf
korset     12   234      sdf
111        13   213      sdf
asd         9   123123   sdf
```

In my `Labbrapport` table, there is only one entry, with the foreign key of `Ärende.ID = 12`, but it is listed on `ÄrendeID` 10, 13 and 9 as well? What should I do to get an output similar to this:

```
Foto    ÄrendeID  Ärende    Labb
1123       10       asd 
korset     12       234      sdf
111        13       213
asd         9       123123
```

Cheers

Comment: You have three tables in your select and only one join clause.  You need to complete the relationships first. I would help write it but you did not provide table definitions so I Have no idea how Labbrapport relates to Foto or Arendet.

Comment: See (and embrace!) [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) and stop just listing tables in a comma-separated list - use proper ANSI JOIN syntax and define your JOIN conditions properly

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT f.Korsnamn AS Foto, ä.ID AS ÄrendeID, ä.Kortnamn AS Ärende, l.Kortnamn AS Labb
FROM Foto f, Ärendet ä, Labbrapport l
WHERE f.ÄrendeID = ä.ID
AND l.ÄrendeID = f.ÄrendeID
```

Comment: you may need to make this an outer join as well - i f i now understand your question..

Answer (score 0):

Add the `join` condition between `Labbrapport` and `Ärendet` as well. e.g. below:

```
SELECT f.Korsnamn AS Foto, ä.ID AS ÄrendeID, ä.Kortnamn AS Ärende, 
       l.Kortnamn AS Labb
FROM Foto f, Ärendet ä, Labbrapport l
WHERE f.ÄrendeID = ä.ID
      AND ä.ID = l.ID;
```

Please use the correct `join key` column of `Labbrapport` in above query.

Answer (score 0):

use LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN depends on which table is your main. In your case use LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT f.Korsnamn AS Foto, ä.ID AS ÄrendeID, ä.Kortnamn AS Ärende, 
   l.Kortnamn AS Labb
FROM Foto f 
INNER JOIN Ärendet ä ON f.ÄrendeID = ä.ID
LEFT JOIN Labbrapport l ON ä.ID = l.ID
```